# How can I add space to the text of my spinner control without creating a layout resource file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I want to add space between texts without creating a design resource file.
how can I do it ?

[image]

```
 val lista = arrayOf("ENERO", "MARZO", "MAYO", "ABRIL","JUNIO","ENERO", "MARZO", "MAYO", "ABRIL","JUNIO" )
        val adaptador1 = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista)
        spinner.adapter = adaptador1
        bt_calcular.setOnClickListener {
            val v1 = tv_valor1.text.toString().toInt()
            val v2 = tv_valor2.text.toString().toInt()
            var resultado = 0
            when (spinner.selectedItem.toString()) {
                "Suma" ->   resultado = v1 + v2
                "Resta" -> resultado = v1 - v2
                "Multiplicar" -> resultado = v1 * v2
                "Dividir" -> {
                    if (v2 !=0){
                        resultado = v1/v2
                    }
                    else{
                        tv_valor2.error = "Ingrese un valor diferete a 0"
                    }
                }
            }
            tv_resultado.text = resultado.toString()
        }
```

Comment: If you are referring to the rows in your drop-down list, that is controlled by your `SpinnerAdapter`, not the `<Spinner>` itself.

Comment: I'm a beginner, but how do I do it.

Comment: Your [mcve] does not show your `SpinnerAdapter` implementation. Somewhere, in your Java or Kotlin code, you are creating an `ArrayAdapter` or some other `SpinnerAdapter` implementation. You are teaching that adapter how to create your rows, whether by inflating some layout or by creating widgets directly in Java/Kotlin code. You will need to modify that to add more space, just as you would need to modify that if you wanted to change the font size, the color of the words, etc.

Comment: my code is up, please a example

Comment: The best solution, by far, is to create your own layout resource that describes how you want those rows to look, then use that layout resource instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`. You indicated that you do not want to do that. I do not know why. I do not have any examples of creating an `ArrayAdapter` that creates its rows any other way. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use layout below

> android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

instead

> android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

Comment: well if the android layout doesn't work out, make a custom layout of your need. thats the only choice left.